# c# DevExpress PopupMenu dynamically populating items

Tags: c#, devexpress, popupmenu

I am trying to populate DevExpress PopuMenu Items dynamically, however, it only only displays Items (BarButtonItem), not Groups (BarLinkContainerItem):

```
        BarManager barManager1 = new BarManager();
        barManager1.Form = this;

        PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(barManager1);

        BarButtonItem item1 = new BarButtonItem(barManager1, "Action1");

        BarButtonItem item2 = new BarButtonItem(barManager1, "Action2");

        BarLinkContainerItem menuGroup1 = new BarLinkContainerItem();
        menuGroup1.Caption = "Group1";

        menu.ItemLinks.Add(item1);
        menu.ItemLinks.Add(menuGroup1);
        menuGroup1.ItemLinks.Add(item2);

        menu.ShowPopup(Cursor.Position);
```

I want to display PopupMenu Onclick event of button: [image: As you see only Items are displayed, group is not added. Action2 in fact must be added to Group1]

Thanks.

Comment: You should definitely not add the `menuGroup1` twice to the `barManager1`. In addition you add it to the `menu.ItemLinks` as well. Because this is not enough you're reusing items you added to the `barManager1` again to add them to the `menuGroup1`. I would be confused as well if I was that PopupMenu.

Comment: Your popup menu displays anything your want: `item1`, `menuGroup1` and `item2` in `menuGroup2`. It's unclear what a problem? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Dear All. sorry for late response. Pls, see my edits. I want to Action1, Group1 {with Action 2} into PopupMenu and display the PopupMenu OnClick event of button. Pls, see image: Group1 is not displayed and Action2 in fact should be displayed under Group1. Thanks.